# How do you set up Caddy Server to work within WSL?

Tags: authentication, ssl, cookies, wsl-2, caddy

## Context

I'm trying to learn how to use secure cookies using a very simple `nodejs` server that returns basic html over `localhost:3000`. I was told I would need to set up a reverse proxy in order to get SSL working so you can best have your development environment mimic that of what production would be like. I realize that I can learn how secure cookies work over localhost without a reverse proxy, but I wanted the challenge and to learn how to get SSL set up in a development environment.

## Setup

I personally prefer to develop in `WSL` (WSL 2, Ubuntu-20.04) so naturally I set up the node server in `WSL` along with `Caddy Server` with the following configuration provided by the [levelup tutorials course](https://www.leveluptutorials.com/tutorials/level-2-node-authentication) I'm using to teach me about web authentication. I ran `Caddy Server` by running `caddy run` in the directory I had the following file.

```
{
    local_certs
}

nodeauth.dev {
    reverse_proxy 127.0.0.1:3000
}
```

The following were the startup logs for the `Caddy Server`

```
2021/07/01 00:53:18.253 INFO    using adjacent Caddyfile
2021/07/01 00:53:18.256 WARN    input is not formatted with 'caddy fmt' {"adapter": "caddyfile", "file": "Caddyfile", "line": 2}
2021/07/01 00:53:18.258 INFO    admin   admin endpoint started  {"address": "tcp/localhost:2019", "enforce_origin": false, "origins": ["localhost:2019", "[::1]:2019", "127.0.0.1:2019"]}
2021/07/01 00:53:18.262 INFO    tls.cache.maintenance   started background certificate maintenance      {"cache": "0xc0003c5260"}
2021/07/01 00:53:18.281 INFO    http    server is listening only on the HTTPS port but has no TLS connection policies; adding one to enable TLS {"server_name": "srv0", "https_port": 443}
2021/07/01 00:53:18.281 INFO    http    enabling automatic HTTP->HTTPS redirects        {"server_name": "srv0"}
2021/07/01 00:53:18.450 INFO    pki.ca.local    root certificate is already trusted by system   {"path": "storage:pki/authorities/local/root.crt"}
2021/07/01 00:53:18.451 INFO    http    enabling automatic TLS certificate management   {"domains": ["nodeauth.dev"]}
2021/07/01 00:53:18.452 INFO    tls     cleaning storage unit   {"description": "FileStorage:/home/rtclements/.local/share/caddy"}
2021/07/01 00:53:18.454 INFO    tls     finished cleaning storage units
2021/07/01 00:53:18.454 WARN    tls     stapling OCSP   {"error": "no OCSP stapling for [nodeauth.dev]: no OCSP server specified in certificate"}
2021/07/01 00:53:18.456 INFO    autosaved config (load with --resume flag)      {"file": "/home/rtclements/.config/caddy/autosave.json"}
2021/07/01 00:53:18.456 INFO    serving initial configuration
```

I also added `127.0.0.1 nodeauth.dev` to the `hosts` file in `WSL` at `/etc/hosts`. Below is the resulting file.

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       MSI.localdomain MSI
192.168.99.100  docker
127.0.0.1       nodeauth.dev

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

## Problem

Interestingly enough, I was able to hit the node server via my browser by navigating to `localhost:3000` (as expected), and was able to hit the `Caddy Server` by navigating to `localhost:2019`. The following was the log outputted by `Caddy Server` when I hit it.

```
2021/07/01 00:53:32.224 INFO    admin.api       received request        {"method": "GET", "host": "localhost:2019", "uri": "/", "remote_addr": "127.0.0.1:34390", "headers": {"Accept":["*/*"],"User-Agent":["curl/7.68.0"]}}
```

I am not, however, able to see the html from my node server in my browser by navigating to `nodeauth.dev`. Neither am I seeing any output from running `curl nodeauth.dev` in my console in `WSL`, whereas I get the expected output when I run `curl localhost:3000` also in `WSL`. Why is this?

I figured it had to do something with the `hosts` file on `Windows` not including this configuration. So I tried modifying that file to look like this, but I still couldn't get it to work.

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

192.168.99.100  docker
127.0.0.1       nodeauth.dev
```

I tried running a powershell script that I barely understand that I found from [here](https://fearthecowboy.com/tutorial/2020/09/17/Code-Serrver-On-WSL.html), but that didn't work either, and I was no longer able to access `localhost:3000`. I'm guessing it does some form of port forwarding. Code below.

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{
  $arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
  Break
}

# create the firewall rule to let in 443/80
if( -not ( get-netfirewallrule -displayname web -ea 0 )) {
  new-netfirewallrule -name web -displayname web -enabled true -profile any -action allow -localport 80,443 -protocol tcp 
}

$remoteport = bash.exe -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '"
$found = $remoteport -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}';

if( $found ){
  $remoteport = $matches[0];
} else{
  echo "The Script Exited, the ip address of WSL 2 cannot be found";
  exit;
}

$ports=@(80,443);

iex "netsh interface portproxy reset";
for( $i = 0; $i -lt $ports.length; $i++ ){
  $port = $ports[$i];
  iex "netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=$port connectport=$port connectaddress=$remoteport";
}
iex "netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4";
```

The only thing that worked was when I ran `Caddy Server` on `Windows` with the same configuration and changes to the `hosts` files as shown before. I'm not terribly sure what's going on here, but would any of y'all happen to know?

Comment: FYI, `/etc/hosts` doesn't look at ports, just hostnames and IPs, so `127.0.0.1:3000  nodeauth.dev` should just be `127.0.0.1  nodeauth.dev`.

Comment: thanks, i updated the question. Turns out it didn't change anything